# If else clause in data object in post request

Tags: jquery, angular, post

the if else is not working i get an error, that there should be an , : before and after else what i'm doing wrong?

```
service.upsert = function (employerId, iban, canOrderCards) {
    let path = 'mask/employer/' + employerId + '/mask/account';
    let data = {
        if(iban == null ){
             isIbanSet: "no"
             }
            else{
              isIbanSet: "yes"
             },
           iban: iban, // string: if undefined the value will not be updated
        canOrderCards: canOrderCards // boolean: if undefined the value will not be updated
    };
    return AuthorizedNetworkService.performRequest(path, 'POST', data);
};
```

i want the if construct to work

Comment: `=` is used for assignment; `==` is used to test equality.

Comment: Thank you but also don't work with ==

Comment: @EdibIsic do you get the same error or?

Comment: Sorry my mobile did it alone

Comment: Why do you need the `if` if you do the same thing in either case?

Comment: Just for testing I will change of course in production

Comment: i think that the if is messing up your object. Try something like `isIbanSet: !iban?null:null`

Comment: yes @BogdanB it's very nice solution and is working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use an if/else statement within an object declaration.
You are always setting the value of isIbanSet to null, I'm going to assume you intend to set it to true or false.

### Ternary

One way to do this would be to use a ternary expression (see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) like so:

```
let data = {
    isIbanSet: iban ? true : false,
    iban: iban,
    canOrderCards: canOrderCards
};
```

---

### If/else

otherwise you could first define the object:

```
let data = {
    iban: iban, // string: if undefined the value will not be updated
    canOrderCards: canOrderCards // boolean: if undefined the value will not be updated
};
```

and then add the last property:

```
if(iban) {
    data['isIbanSet'] = true;
} else {
    data['isIbanSet'] = false;
}
```